# listbox.Additems from single column based on search value from multiple columns range

Tags: vba

I am trying to add value from column D only but if search value is from D, E or F column the offset function adds item from subsequent column. Only column D value needs to be added to the listbox.
The Do loop searches fetches the value but not sure how to fetch values only from specific column.
Please help:

```
    If Len(txtSearchItem.Value) > 3 Then
    Dim rFind, rng, rngdb As Range
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim strItem As String
    
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DB").Columns("C:F")
            Set rFind = .Find(What:=Me.txtSearchItem.Value, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
            Me.lstItem.Clear
            If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
                i = rFind.Row      'rFind.Column & ", Row: " & rFind.Row
                Me.lblDBDescription = xlshdb.Cells(i, 3).Value
                'Me.txtItem.Value = xlshdb.Cells(i, 4).Value
                
                '*****Show the Item list's in list box ****

                With xlshdb.Range("C:C")
                    Set rng = .Cells(LRow)
                End With
                    Set rngdb = xlshdb.Range("C:F").Find(What:=Me.txtSearchItem.Value, After:=rng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False)
            
                    If Not rngdb Is Nothing Then
                        FirstAddr = rngdb.Address
                        Do Until rngdb Is Nothing
                            'Debug.Print rngdb.Address
                            Set rngdb = xlshdb.Range("C:F").FindNext(After:=rngdb)
            
                            Me.lstItem.AddItem rngdb.Offset(0, 1)
                            If rngdb.Address = FirstAddr Then
                                Exit Do
                            End If
                        Loop
                            If Me.lstItem.ListCount > 1 Then
                                Me.txtItem.Visible = False
                                Me.lstItem.Visible = True
                                Me.lstItem.Selected(0) = True
                            Else
                                Me.lstItem.Visible = False
                                Me.txtItem.Visible = True
                                Me.txtItem.Value = xlshdb.Cells(i, 4).Value
                            End If
                    Else
                        Me.lstItem.Clear
                        Me.lstItem.Visible = False
                        Me.txtItem.Visible = True
                        Me.txtItem.Value = xlshdb.Cells(i, 4).Value
                    End If
            Else
                Me.lstItem.Clear
                Me.lstItem.Visible = False
                Me.txtItem.Visible = True
                Me.lblDBDescription = ""
                Me.txtItem = ""

            End If

        End With
     End if
```

Comment: So you're looking down the rows in D:F and you want to additem column D on the found cells row? I would do `Me.lstItem.AddItem .cells(rngdb.row, 4)` . Is that what you're after? It's like using a lastrow or lastcolumn but instead with the row of the found cell.

Comment: @Simon Thank you so much! This works like a charm.God Bless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will just make an answer so there is one.

Simply change the line:

```
Me.lstItem.AddItem rngdb.Offset(0, 1)
```

To:

```
Me.lstItem.AddItem .cells(rngdb.row, 4)
```

We grab the row value of the found cell and use it as our row in the `.Cells` range.